# Problems with Shopware snippets

Tags: shopware

Greeting everyone !

I have a problem - snippets not works.

In Theme.php I use next

```
/**
     * @param Form\Container\TabContainer $container
     */
    public function createConfig(Form\Container\TabContainer $container)
    {
        $container->addTab($this->createBasicTab());
    }

    /**
     * Create Basic Tab
     * @return Form\Container\Tab
     */
    public function createBasicTab()
    {
        $tab = $this->createTab(
            'basic_settings',
            '__basic_settings__',
            [
                'attributes' => [
                    'layout' => 'anchor',
                    'autoScroll' => true,
                    'padding' => '0',
                ],
            ]
        );
```

In snippet located in _private/snippets/backend/config.ini I used next

```
[en_GB]

basic_settings = 'Basic settings'

[de_DE]

basic_settings = 'Basic settings de'
```

And in admin part I got next

[image]

Please, help!(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theme manager we have checkbox `force snippet reload` in settings. Please, enable it. This will save your nerves

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
Shopware()->Snippets()->getNamespace('backend/config')->('__basic_settings__', 'There you can put value by deault')
```

[Documentation](https://developers.shopware.com/designers-guide/snippets/) for snippets.

Comment: It's a snippets for backend(admin part). I looked around themes, all use like `__snippet_name__`. Am I right?

Your variant also didn't work.